# VB Script to apply certain Windows Theme

Tags: vbscript

I have written script that changes my Windows theme by executing it in my directory via the following code:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""C:\Users\[MYUSERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\MyTheme.theme"""

'This part of the code just closes the Explorer window that pops up after the file is executed
Wscript.Sleep 7000
WshShell.AppActivate ("Desktop Properties")
WshShell.SendKeys "%FC"
WshShell.SendKeys "{F4}"
```

I want to make this code accessible to anyone that uses it. Is there a way to instead of using my specific username, use something that would resemble the current user? So make the code universal to anyone without having them have to change the file location or the username in the file path? Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to get Local Application Data path:

```
MsgBox CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%localappdata%")

MsgBox WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("process").Item("localappdata")

MsgBox WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application").NameSpace(&H1C).Self.Path
```

Using that abilities your code may be as follows:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sLocalAppDataPath = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%localappdata%")

WshShell.Run "rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""" & sLocalAppDataPath & "\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\MyTheme.theme"""

'This part of the code just closes the Explorer window that pops up after the file is executed
Wscript.Sleep 7000
WshShell.AppActivate ("Desktop Properties")
WshShell.SendKeys "%FC"
WshShell.SendKeys "{F4}"
```

Note that usage of `.SendKeys` is not the best practice. Would be better if you find a more reliable solution.

**UPD:** Try the code below to close the window:

**UPD2:** I've changed theme application launch string and explorer window contol via IWebBrowser object. I guess that is exactly what you need:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sLocalAppDataPath = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%localappdata%")
Do While GetWnd(oWnd) ' close all control panel windows
    oWnd.Quit
Loop
WshShell.Run "Explorer.exe """ & sLocalAppDataPath & "\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\MyTheme.theme""" ' apply theme
Do Until GetWnd(oWnd) ' wait until personalization window appears
    WScript.Sleep 10
Loop
sLocationName = oWnd.LocationName ' debug
oWnd.Quit ' close appeared personalization window
WScript.Echo sLocationName & " Closed" ' debug


Function GetWnd(oShellWnd)
    On Error Resume Next
    GetWnd = False
    For Each oShellWnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        With oShellWnd
            If InStr(LCase(TypeName(.Document)), "ishell") = 0 Then ' is explorer window, but not internet explorer
            Else
                If InStr(.Document.Folder.Self.Path, "::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}") = 0 Then ' any control panel window
                Else
                    GetWnd = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, I will test it out! I know it's not the best idea to use send keys, but I don't know what else to do. I need to wait the 7000 ms otherwise it sometimes won't close since it needs to wait for the code to finish running. Is there a way to wait for the `WshShell.Run` command to finish running, and only THEN close the Personalization window that pops up?

Comment: According to [description of `.Run` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx) the last argument `bWaitOnReturn` sets if method have to wait or not, but unfortunately in your case you'll wait to `rundll32.exe` to be completed only, and the next process ran from `shell32.dll` that brings control panel window couldn't be catched that way.

Comment: So you're saying that in my case the .run method does not wait for the line to be executed? I'm new to coding so you may have to explain in simple terms. And I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: My short investigation shows that when script containing the only command `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL", 3, True` launched, the sequence should be as follows (+ process starts, - terminated):
+wscript.exe > +rundll32.exe > -rundll32.exe > -wscript.exe > +dllhost.exe > +igfxsrvc.exe > -dllhost.exe > -igfxsrvc.exe. Therefore `WshShell` launches rundll32.exe and it is tracking only this process, but rundll32.exe terminates rapidly. And when I close that control panel window no process terminates at all. I am on Win 7 HB SP1.

Comment: Ah ok. I am on Windows 7 Professional SP1 by the way to be more specific. So with all this, what does this mean or what would you recommend? Because if I want to wait for the command to finish before closing the window I'm not sure where to go from here. Or is there also a way to execute the command without even opening any windows, like doing it in the background?

Comment: Changed theme application launch string and explorer window contol via IWebBrowser.