# How to apply a certain theme on Windows 7 IF it's not applyed?

Tags: vbscript

Here is a little bit modified code from here: [VB Script to apply certain Windows Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247222/vb-script-to-apply-certain-windows-theme)

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""%windir%\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\basic.theme"""
Do Until GetWnd(oWnd) 
    WScript.Sleep 10
Loop
'sLocationName = oWnd.LocationName ' debug
oWnd.Quit 
'WScript.Echo sLocationName & " Closed" ' debug


Function GetWnd(oShellWnd)
    On Error Resume Next
    GetWnd = False
    For Each oShellWnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        With oShellWnd
            If InStr(LCase(TypeName(.Document)), "ishell") = 0 Then 
            Else
                If InStr(.Document.Folder.Self.Path, "::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}") = 0 Then
                Else
                    GetWnd = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Function
```

I need to add a condition that checks active theme and if it's not %windir%\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\basic.theme then all the code above executes. 
It should work on Windows 7.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Change your Tag, please. This code is not VBA. It can be adapted for VBA, but you miss the area where people can give you valuable pieces of advice...

Comment: ok, I changed it to vbscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i've coded it just as i needed. Feel free to use. Debug messages are not commented.
Script works for Windows 7, checks for Current theme in registry and if it's not basic.theme, applies it and closes Personalisation window. Feel free to use.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim currentTheme,ReadTheme
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
currentTheme = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\CurrentTheme"
ReadTheme = WSHShell.RegRead(currentTheme)
'---Reading Reg Values
WSHShell.RegRead(currentTheme)
'---Echo Values for debug
'WScript.Echo WshShell.RegRead(currentTheme)

If Err Then
'---Applying theme if error occured
ApplyBasicTheme()   
Else
    If ReadTheme = "C:\Windows\resources\Ease of Access Themes\basic.theme" Then
    WScript.Echo "It's basic" & WshShell.RegRead(currentTheme) & ", nothing to do" ' debug
    Else
    ApplyBasicTheme()       
    End If
End If

Function ApplyBasicTheme()
    Msgbox "Not basic" & WshShell.RegRead(currentTheme) & ", changing", vbExclamation ' debug
    WshShell.Run "rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""%windir%\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\basic.theme"""
    Do Until GetWnd(oWnd) ' Wait until Personalisation Window appears
        WScript.Sleep 10
    Loop
    'sLocationName = oWnd.LocationName ' debug
    oWnd.Quit ' Close Personalisation Window
    'WScript.Echo sLocationName & " Closed" ' debug
End function

Function GetWnd(oShellWnd)
    On Error Resume Next
    GetWnd = False
        For Each oShellWnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
            With oShellWnd
            If InStr(LCase(TypeName(.Document)), "ishell") = 0 Then ' is explorer window, but not internet explorer
            Else
                If InStr(.Document.Folder.Self.Path, "::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}") = 0 Then ' any control panel window
            Else
            GetWnd = True
        Exit For
                End If
            End If
            End With
    Next
End Function
WScript.Quit
```